# response.sendRedirect Vs getRequestDispatcher

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I have a servlet, called 'insert' that inserts data in a db.

At the end of this servlet I have a `getRequestDispatcher` that sends the user to a page called 'outcome.jsp'. My servlet send also a variable to outcome.jsp with  `request.setAttribute("Message", "bla bla bla");`

In outcome.jsp i have a `request.getAttribute("Message");` and i show to the user the value of Message.

On the browser url there's always the url of my servlet (http://www.site.com/insert), so the user could use the reload button of the browser and makes the insert 1000000000 times.

I tried using response.sendRedirect but i cant use `request.setAttribute`, and i need it to show message about the insert outcome

How can i avoid the url of my servlet is shown on the browser url in order not to allow user to make infinite inserts by using the reload button?

Thank you

Comment: follow PRG(Post Redirect Get) pattern http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get

Comment: Which ever of the two you use you will still have the same problem. The check of double inserting should be done separately

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which ever of the two methods you use you will still have the same problem (Even in the case of `sendRedirect()` by capturing and reproducing the request header by the user  ). The check of double inserting should be done separately.

Usually, if you want to disable a double entry from a client, you can create a token and send it to the client. When the client wants to make an insert, you can check if this token is valid and then do the insert (AND then remove token from the valid list).

That is just one of many ways....

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

If use response.sendRedirect(), a new request will start so you can not access the data you set for your previous request, to show the data you have to use the query parameter, that will append to URl

```
   response.sendRedirect("/outcome.jsp?Message=bla bla")
```

In your jsp page you need to read as

```
request.getParameter("Message")
```